# How can I use a wordpress post title in a calculated form field?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms

I want to populate a calculated form field with a post title, which is a number, and use that field in other calculations.
The post title is dynamic (daily exchange rate) so one day is 4.9112, another is 4.8492 and so on.

Here's what I've tried:

For example, when I use this script (with a static value):

```
<script> rate =4.9197 </script>
```

it works to use the **rate** value for a calculation:

```
`(function(){
var v = fieldname2*((fieldname16 == 'Euro') ? rate: 1);

if(v <= 450000) return 0;
return PREC((v-450000)*.03, 0);
})()`
```

But I need something like this (where the **rate** value is a post_id title):

```
<script> rate =<?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?></script>
```

In my case the post_id is 8331.

Does anyone know how I can write the script, so the **rate** value is the 8331 post_id's title?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the posttitle you can find them in the Developer Tools of Chrome or Firefox in the DOM.

Inspect your code and find the selector.

The following selector is just a example. You have to inspect your DOM.

```js
var title = $('#post-8331').text();
console.log('Your title - ', title);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="post-8331">Post Title 4494</article>
```

You are in Wordpress. I'm not so familiar with wordpress. I think you have to add this in the functions.php file.

```php
<?php
/* Inline script printed out in the header */
add_action('wp_head', 'my_script_wp_head');
function my_script_wp_head() {
    ?>
        <script>
            console.log("I'm an inline script tag added to the header.");
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

or if you like to outsource it to a special file. Create the file custom.js in the folder scripts and place your javascript code there.

```php
/* Custom script with no dependencies, enqueued in the header */
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script_enqueue_custom_js');
function my_script_enqueue_custom_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/scripts/custom.js');
}
```

See this tutorial how to include custom js to wordpress:
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-custom-javascript-to-your-wordpress-site--cms-34368

Comment: I need to use the title of a specific post, 8331 in my case.

Comment: Just expect the DOM. There is a class post-id with the number 8331 and you can get it through jquery or JavaScript.

Comment: This is new to me. How can I do this exactly? This is the post 8331: https://notariate.ro/4-7545/
How can I write the script ?

Comment: Can you please tell me where to add the above code? I've added it on the page where the form is, and it doesn't work. 
Thanks

Comment: I've tried both in fuctions.php and in snippets (a custom code plugin) and unfortunately neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet looks like it could work, assuming the post_title is purely a number like you said: 4.9197 or 4.8492.

You could wrap the PHP portion with `parseFloat()`

```
<script> var rate = parseFloat(<?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?>);</script>
```

**EDIT:**

What I see:

[image: Screenshot.png]

The snippet of code I first gave needs to be added via PHP in something like the functions.php file of your WordPress Child Theme. If that is not possible, then you can try this in pure javascript:

```
<script>
    var rate = parseFloat(document.querySelector('meta[property="og:title"]').content);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, the post title is always only a number. Today is 4.9197.
I've added 
`<script> var rate = parseFloat(<?php echo get_the_title(8331); ?>);</script>` 
but it doesn't work

Comment: @LucianBarligea I went to your website and I do not see the script tag rendered as `<script> var rate = parseFloat(4.9227);</script>` ? Where is it supposed to be?

Comment: I've added your code here: https://notariate.ro/testcode/

Comment: See my Edit @LucianBarligea

Comment: I've added `<script> var rate = parseFloat(<?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?>);</script>`  in the theme's functions.php, but it doesn't work.